# Downloading spring 3.0 with dependencies?

Tags: spring, download

where can i find out spring 3 version with all dependencies?

i don't see any such link @ http://www.springsource.com/download/community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are going to provide this kind of distribution for Spring 3.0.1: [JIRA issue](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6575). Originally Spring team decided not to do it for Spring 3, but after many complaints they changed their mind.

Comment: is there any place we have it currently/

Answer (score 1):

Some of the older releases still have -with-dependencies.zip files that you can download.  The latest version I see with dependencies is 3.0.2.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/dist.springframework.org/release/SPR/spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies.zip

You can also create the ZIP yourself for more recent versions using these instructions

http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/03/building-spring-3/

Answer (score -2):

You can download all JAR files which are hosted in the Maven repository like Spring inclusive their dependencies from here: http://jar-download.com/